# Fetch Record From Xml

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here's my XML:

```
DECLARE @ChargeDetail xml

SET @ChargeDetail ='
    <Amount>
       <First>
          <Second>1</Second>
          <Second>2</Second>
       </First>
    </Amount>'
```

and I'm using this query:

```
SELECT tc.value('Second[1]','varchar(max)') as ID 
FROM @ChargeDetail.nodes('/Amount/First') as tb(tc)
```

I want the output to be:

```
ID
1
2
```

but this query return only 1

pls help me in this....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select T.X.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as ID
from @ChargeDetail.nodes('/Amount/First/Second') as T(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tb.tc.value('.','varchar(max)') as ID 
FROM    @ChargeDetail.nodes('//Amount/First/Second') as tb(tc)
```

Comment: Woops, seems like Mikael posted before me, should I delete my post?